# Accept superclass as parameter but use subclass in method

Tags: java, class, generics, polymorphism

thanks in advance for your answers.
I might not have all the necessary knowledge to form the question correctly but here it goes:
I have a bunch of classes that extend the Shape super class (Circle, Rectangle, Point).
I have a static class Geometry with a method that checks intersection between different shapes (circles, rectangles, triangles).
In "Geometry" static class I implemented the "intersects" method to accept any combination of shapes

```
  public static boolean intersects(Rectangle rect, Point point) {
    return rectIntersectsPoint(rect, point);
  }
  public static boolean intersects(Circle circle, Point point) {
    return circleIntersectsPoint(circle, point);
  }
  public static boolean intersects(Circle circle, Rectangle rect) {
    return circleIntersectsRect(circle, rect);
  }
```

And a bunch more for each case.
Now, in my program I have a method that has to check intersection and has to accept any subclass of Shape:

```
  List<Point> query(Shape shape) {
    if (Geo.intersects(this.b, shape)) {
      return this.found;
    }
   ......
  }
```

And I use it like this:

```
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(10, 10, 200, 300);
found = qt.query(rect );
```

But i get an error saying "The function intersects expects parameters like (Rectangle, Circle)".

So I'm passing a Rectangle object to the query() method, and it goes well because I can accept any subclass of "Shape". But when I use it in the method it doesn't keep it's "Rectangle" type and becomes a "Shape" object.

I thought about having the query method for each subclass but that way I'll have the same code over and over.

Comment: The **object** is still a `Rectangle`, but the **variable** is a `Shape`.

Comment: Ok, so how can I accept any Shape sub type, but still have it as it was passed when the method was used?

Comment: The only thing I can think of would be to change your method signature to: `<T extends Shape> List<Point> query(T shape)` - However, I feel like the compiler would still complain about a type mismatch. A better option might be to create a single `intersects` method that accepts two `Shape`s, determine what `Shape`s they are at runtime, and then handle them from there.

Comment: Tried with <T extends... but i still get an  error. Your second advice would mean I would have to hava an ifelse statement based on the type which I understand is not good practice when dealing with subclasses.

Comment: @heraphim Not necessarily; one option would be to create a `Map` which maps the child class to the method that determines the intersection. Another would be to modify your child classes and have them handle intersections with different shapes themselves.

Comment: I'm going to look at the "Map" option, having eac sub class have method that checks an intersection with every other shape means I'll have the same code for both Circle.intersects(Rectangle) and for Rectangle.intersects(Circle) and that is what I'm trying to avoid. I know there's a lot of methods to solve this. What I'm trying to find is the most elegant way to do it, and I'm sure there's a way to do it like I'm trying to. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

**Polymorphism** allows you to call the appropriate method for the actual type of the object, regardless of the declared type of reference.

And **double dispatch** allows you to call the appropriate method for two object types.

Here's a sketch (not compiled or tested):

```
public abstract class Shape {
    public abstract boolean intersects( Shape that );

    public abstract boolean intersects(Rectangle that);
    public abstract boolean intersects(Circle that);
}

public class Circle extends Shape {
    public boolean intersects( Shape that ) {
        return that.intersects( this );   // 'this' is of type Circle
    }

    public boolean intersects( Rectangle that ) { ... }
    public boolean intersects( Circle that ) { ... }
}

public class Rectangle extends Shape {
    public boolean intersects( Shape that ) {
        return that.intersects( this );   // 'this' is of type Rectangle
    }

    public boolean intersects( Rectangle that ) { ... }
    public boolean intersects( Circle that ) { ... }
}
```

You can avoid redundancy by either defining one of a pair to call the other -- or having both methods call a common implementation. An example of the former is:

```
public class Rectangle {
    ...
    public boolean intersects( Circle that ) {
       return that.intersects( this ); 
    }
```

Now, say you pass a Circle and a Rectangle to the method below.

```
public boolean intersects( Shape shape1, Shape shape2 ) {
    return shape1.intersects( shape2 );
}
```

At compile-time, the compiler doesn't know what method will be called. But at run-time, the `Circle.intersects(Shape)` method will be called. It will call `Rectangle.intersects( Circle )`.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a modified [visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) with nested visitors. I'll demonstrate with 2 shapes for brevity:

```
abstract class Shape {
    abstract <V extends Visitor> V accept(V v);
}

class Circle extends Shape {
    @Override
    <V extends Visitor> V accept(V v) {
        v.visit(this);
        return v;
    }
}

class Rectangle extends Shape {
    @Override
    <V extends Visitor> V accept(V v) {
        v.visit(this);
        return v;
    }
}

interface Visitor {
    void visit(Circle c);
    void visit(Rectangle r);
}

static boolean intersects(Shape s1, Shape s2) {
    return s1.accept(new Visitor() {
        boolean intersects;

        @Override
        public void visit(Circle left) {
            s2.accept(new Visitor() {
                @Override
                public void visit(Circle right) {
                    intersects = circleIntersectsCircle(left, right);
                }

                @Override
                public void visit(Rectangle right) {
                    intersects = circleIntersectsRect(left, right);
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void visit(Rectangle left) {
            s2.accept(new Visitor() {
                @Override
                public void visit(Circle right) {
                    intersects = circleIntersectsRect(right, left);
                }

                @Override
                public void visit(Rectangle right) {
                    intersects = rectIntersectsRect(left, right);
                }
            });
        }
    }).intersects;
}
```